Solana transfers USDT, the transaction is pushed successfully and the hash of the transaction is returned, but the transaction is not packaged
The current situation is that sol transfers can be successfully packaged and the browser can find the sent transactions, but only contract coins (e.g. USDT) frequently appear to be pushed successfully but the browser can not be found, has anyone encountered a similar situation? How to solve it?
